# Facing issue while sending mail in gmail mule esb

Tags: smtp, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

When i tried to send mail in gmail i got following error. In gmail global connector i add fromAddress,replyToAddress and all....

```
********************************************************************************

WARN  2015-02-10 10:58:28,526 [[mailexample].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
INFO  2015-02-10 10:58:31,354 [[mailexample].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.security.tls.TlsPropertiesMapper: Defaulting mule.email.smtps trust store to client Key Store
WARN  2015-02-10 10:58:31,355 [[mailexample].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.security.tls.TlsProperties: File tls-default.conf not found, using default configuration.
ERROR 2015-02-10 10:58:33,485 [[mailexample].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to connect to mail transport.
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuRg
534-5.7.14 yGa3WdTfxBAchlMvo6NtJgJK6JL823P9UTvFhfcpUfm5tgTi4Zzdsm1J9NfGCqjG4iAvCi
534-5.7.14 6BRop8ALCvZUrZ1sa9ICkR_u-WykguB7aGSc5jLH5mH1FGGlkusqWnqTyvE-AhRNcJo-PQ
534-5.7.14 rH1WuTiUITDEFdAlfy19PaiFDED6aos2shRxO4-jdEHzGGUTmgFXWUthbF5nSKBPq76Eb5
534-5.7.14 s5b7LbA> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 c17sm18040119pdl.6 - gsmtp
 (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException)
  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator:648 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.html)
2. Unable to connect to mail transport. (org.mule.api.endpoint.EndpointException)
  org.mule.transport.email.SmtpMessageDispatcher:67 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/endpoint/EndpointException.html)
```

In browser i got following error

```
Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://<emailaddress>%40gmail.com:<password>@smtp.gmail.com, connector=GmailSmtpConnector
{
  name=smtpGmailConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=103a0ec
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[smtp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.smtp.emailaddress.gmail.com', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={toAddresses=to_emailaddress@gmail.com, subject=Test email message, fromAddress=emailaddress}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: MimeMessage
```

following is my flow

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="emailConnector" />
 <flow name="mailTestFlow1" doc:name="mailTestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" 
        path="sendMail"/>
        <component doc:name="Java" class="Component1"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" 
        user="yourEmailAddress%40gmail.com" password="pass" to="javaroots@gmail.com" 
        from="yourEmailAddress%40gmail.com" subject="Testing mule" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="gmail" doc:name="Send notification email"/>
    </flow>
```

Now,What changes i have to do??

Comment: Supply the **gmail** connector configuration.

Comment: I add gmail connector, Now I got diff error..I update my question.Please check once

Comment: what happens if you use port 465 instead of 587?

Comment: 465 is also didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please check below conditions in the smtp endpoint

1. if the password contains any character that can be decoded, then specify the decoded password.
2. test by giving from address with out @gmail.com

3.Specify the `<email:string-to-email-transformer/>` transformer

`<smtp:outbound-endpoint  ...... doc:name="email-notification">
          <email:string-to-email-transformer/>
</smtp:outbound-endpoint>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi.My pwd doesn't contain any special character.. I did above three steps as you mention. but still getting the same error...

Comment: can you try with below flow definition  ,
check if the global configuration contains below definition

 <email:email-to-string-transformer name="Email_to_String" doc:name="Email to String"/>
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>


And smtp outbound definition as below:
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" user="XXX%40gmail.com" password="XXX" to="XXXX@gmail.com" from="wslreference" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="Email_to_String" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="Gmail"/>

Comment: ya I tried it with another account..its work.but mail goes to spam folder?why so?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en

its gmail security issues i guess,
if the answer serves your need in mule flow implementation, please tick markit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SMTP+Transport+Reference#highlighter_324568), the GMail connector needs to be configured with non-escaped `@` signs:

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="smtpGmailConnector"
    bccAddresses="abc@example.com" ccAddresses="bcd@example.com"
    contentType="foo/bar" fromAddress="cde@example.com"
    replyToAddresses="def@example.com" subject="subject">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..Now I got Authentication error..I update my question...My email id and pwd are correct...still i got error

Comment: Hard to debug your problem from here: try putting a breakpoint in the SMTP client to see exactly what credentials are used when connecting to GMail.

Answer (score 1):

You are using connector-ref="gmail". Try using connector-ref="emailConnector" instead, It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following configuration running:

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="GmailConnector" contentType="text/html" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>
...
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" user="${smtp.user}" password="${smtp.password}" connector-ref="GmailConnector" to="${smtp.to}" subject="${smtp.subject}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
```

The config.properties file contains:

```
#  
# SMTP Configuration
#
smtp.user=focadiz
smtp.password=xXxXxXxXxX
smtp.to=email@domain.com
smtp.subject=Mule Notification
```